# "file in use by another process" error while trying to delete a database file

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a `PC.sdf` file that I work with. I close the connection and I need to delete it.

I open the connection like this:

```
bool OpenConn()
{
  try
  {
     Conn = new SqlCeConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source={0}\{1}", PathI, "PC.SDF"));
     Conn.Open();
     return true;
   }
   catch 
   {
      //MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Connetion error");
      return false;
   }
}
```

I close it like this:

```
Conn.Close();
Conn.Dispose();
```

I try to delete it like this:

```
if (File.Exists(@"\myPath\PC.sdf"))
    File.Delete(@"\myPath\PC.sdf");
```

But I get this error: `file in use by another process`. What could be the cause of this error, and how can I fix it?

Comment: I believe you have to check your code for other connections, cause there is something yet locking that file...

Comment: @Gali, something else in the system might be sitting on the file you want to remove. I'd suggest you try using something like [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to determine the process(es) that still have an open handle to your database file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try and force garbage collection by running

```
GC.Collect();
```

Do this after you have Closed and Disposed of the DB object.

This will of course only work if that is the only reference to that database file.

Edit: Answer to comment about that you shouldn't use GC.Collect to "fix" other issues.

I don't think this is because of another issue. The garbage collector runs at an indeterminate time chosen by the runtime. This means that you can't rely on your object being disposed of between the followings lines.

```
Conn.Dispose();
//Nothing says GC will run exactly now
File.Delete(@"C:\Some-file-used-by-Conn.db");
```

Your options are to force garbage collection or to delay the deletion in some way.

Comment: You should avoid calling GC.Collect() to try to "fix" other issues.  This is a bad practice.

Comment: @tsells: I don't think this is because of another issue. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm not sure that GC.Collect() guarantees collection, it only requests the GC come along and clean up. So, in this case you might still get an error because the GC might not have got around to it.

Comment: Calling GC.Collect() is not a good practice.  It's best to leave this up to the Collector to determine when to cleanup the object.  The only time you should ever have to call dispose directly is if you are trying to release unmanaged resources before the Garbage Collector will release them.  In this case - by implementing the IDisposable with the Using(Connection) clause you remove the handles to the file to allow them to be deleted.

Comment: If the connection object is implemented correctly, then Dispose will perform all necessary clean-up, even if the object were never garbage collected (e.g. because you keep a reference to it). The garbage collection is only relevant if you forget to dispose, in which case the clean-up is often done by a [Finalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.finalize.aspx) method instead. Normally the `Dispose` implementation will call `GC.SuppressFinalize` to disable that fall-back because the object is already properly cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I would try it like this below.  This puts your connection inside a using block which will call dispose the connection for you once it goes out of scope.  This should allow you to delete the file immediately after as all of the file locks associated with it should be released.

```
bool OpenConn()
{
  try
  {
     using(Conn = new SqlCeConnection(String.Format(@"Data Source={0}\{1}", PathI, "PC.SDF")))
     {
        Conn.Open();
        return true;
     }
   }
   catch 
   {
      //MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Connetion error");
      return false;
   }
}

if (File.Exists(@"\myPath\PC.sdf"))
    File.Delete(@"\myPath\PC.sdf");
```

Comment: That seems like it would close the connection on the way out of OpenConn() which would defeat the open that we're expecting from openconn()

Comment: The point here was to test.  You should really only open the connection right before you use it.  When you call another method to do this for you - you risk hiding some logic that may affect your processes.

Answer (score 0):

The two responses above are both good considerations for ensuring that it is not YOUR application which is the one using the database file.

I'm not exactly sure what an .SDF file is, but a quick google search suggests that it may be a MS SQL database file. If so, depending on your system and your operating conditions, you may want to consider using the ALTER DATABASE SET SINGLE_USER command:

```
ALTER DATABASE [YourDbName]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/11/sql-server-alter-database-dbname-set-single_user-with-rollback-immediate/

Comment: an SDF file is a SQL Compact CE file.  There is no database server.